# why is BufferedImage initialized faster than Image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I'm running some tests for my project written in Java, about images. I got an interesting result and cannot figure out why. Here is the initialization lines of `BufferedImage` and `Image`.

```
File[] files = new File("C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Desktop\\img\\").listFiles();
time = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (File f:files){
    Image img = ImageIO.read(f);
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " miliseconds.");
```

**BEWARE**: These two operations are run separately. I run the above one, process ends, I mean actually gets killed ends, than I run the below one.

```
File[] files = new File("C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Desktop\\img\\").listFiles();  
time = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (File f:files){
    BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(f);
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " miliseconds.");
```

I'm aware that running these in a run may affect results as I try to reach same files, for that I run them separately. The results are near 40 minutes. However, `BufferedImage` initialization is always a minute faster than `Image` initialization. Why is that?

I run the tests three times and the result is the same.

Comment: This isn't a valid test, you're invoking the same method but just assigning it with a different type.

Comment: You may also find that the first loop is caching the image results which the second loop is taking advantage of (not needing to read the image again)

Comment: There's no difference in initialization. All that's different is the reference type you assign the result of `ImageIO.red(f)` to. The reason was given by iluxa: when the second loop is run, hotspot already has had the chance to optimize the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Times should be identical. I suspect your first loop is warming up some caches with the files' content, and the second loop has an easier time at it.

Try reversing the reading order: first `BufferedImages`, then `Images`, and check what happens

Comment: "I'm aware that running these in a run may affect results as I try to reach same files, for that I run them separately." I'm pasting the full code.

Comment: Still. Hard drive caches are also a thing. The most conclusive test would look like this: reboot the computer, run 1 version, reboot it again, run the second one.

Comment: I run the Image, than I run BufferedImage (let's say it's cached), I run Image again, than I run BufferedImage. I get the same results. anyway, I'll give it a try and post the results.

Comment: How many files are we talking about? is it a smallish number of large files, or a very large number of tiny ones? Another test I'd suggest - try opening just one file in a loop 10K times and see whether there's any difference there

Comment: 60k files, results will be here soon.

Comment: 60K = 1.5K a minute = 25 a second = 40ms per file, so CPU performance should have nothing to do with this... hmmm..... interesting

Comment: buffered image is still lower, but results are closer. I agree that times should be identical. I needed for a report I'm handing and I needed reasonable results, that's why I've been a little nasty:) thank you for your interest.

Comment: The only difference is that a BufferedImage (as created by ImageIO) gets down-casted into just Image... I can't imagine that taking a long time though... OK, another test: Open a single BufferedImage, and down-cast it to an Image in a loop, see if that takes any time at all

Comment: it took 2 miliseconds for 10k images:)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you do more than one run of a test like that (i.e. stick the entire loop in a loop), secondly use System.NanoTime as it's WAY more accurate, thirdly as the other poster suggested, try altering the execution order or doing your runs in isolation (probably the safest way).

Comment: a minute doesn't need nanotime, I guess.